# how to convert a list of byte arrays to a single multi-page tiff image in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, tiff, multipage

as I searched on internet it is easy to convert a list of byte arrays to a single multi-page .tiff image in windows application (by c# language). the application uses System.Drawing namespace which is not supported in silverlight.

the obvious question is, how to do such in a silverlight application?

Comment: I found that silverlight does not support .tiff (and also .gif) file format. by such situation what is the solution for having a single file with multi-page pictures in a silverlight application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LibTiff.Net library](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) supports Silverlight.

You can use the library to create TIFF images in a Silverlight application. There are [samples for various TIFF-related tasks](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples) available.

Source code package of the library contains Silverlight Test Application that shows how to display TIFFs in a Silverlight application.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Comment: thanks for your help, your response solvel my problem